# Using a font from fontforge in command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, fonts, truetype-fonts

I want to have a character usable in command prompt that is a right facing triangle with the full height of the line, the same height as the block character. I first tried with the private character editor, but it kept changing the proportions, and I couldn't create a full height character. Then I tried editing the consolas font with FontForge, placing the character at U+2589, and renaming it ConsolasPlusOne. I installed the font for all users, and it worked in most places such as notepad and character map, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbTyw.png)

But the font is not available for command prompt. I tried adding a value in the registry editor at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`, adding `000: ConsolasPlusOne`, and I made sure that `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` contained `ConsolasPlusOne (TrueType): ConsolasPlusOne.ttf`. I also made sure the font was marked as monospace in FontForge, and that all of the glyphs were the same size. However, the font still does not appear as an option in command prompt.

I believe it may be because the font doesn't have a bold counterpart, but I'm not sure. What else can I do to get the font to appear in command prompt?

Comment: Have you rebooted after the changes? It may be that the command prompt is still loaded somewhere in windows and doesn't check for installed fonts as that only happens at program launch.

Comment: Yes, I've rebooted but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Could you post online your new font?

Comment: the font is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jMveHf2LVNDtSclIXm5jzF3ugToxWSJd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The font I find in Windows has the file-name of `Consolaz` and is different from yours on too many parameters to evaluate. I suggest to redo it, starting from `C:\Windows\Fonts\consolaz.ttf`.

Comment: As another note, you can't claim the font as yours after modifying it. It remains the property of Microsoft.

Comment: @harrymc No, consolaz.ttf is the bold and italisized version of consola.ttf, consolai.ttf is just italics, consolab.ttf is just bold and consola.ttf is the main font, but opening consola.ttf gives the font name Consolas. Also, are you sure the copyright and all that will matter as long as I don't distribute it? I don't see why Windows would check it.

Comment: Windows checks nothing, just a note.